# How to annotate a ternary expression with `[[likely]]`?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20, is there a way to annotate a ternary expression with `[[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` to hint the compiler which of the two outcomes is more likely?

The following syntax doesn't seem to work

```
condition ? [[likely]] function1() : function2()
```

Is there a different syntax to annotate ternary expressions? Or will I have to use an `if` instead?

Comment: The compiler doesn't care which is more likely. If you do, as a reader of the code, add a comment.

Comment: I don't think so: _"...These attributes may be applied to labels and statements..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely and the clauses of the conditional operator are expressions - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: Update: this _"thing"_ compiles but (a) it's a _"thing"_ and (b) I don't think it does what you want it to .... `condition() ? []{[[likely]] function1();}() : function2();` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/To3jo1frq

Comment: @jkb: The compiler can be made to care, that's the whole point of `[[likely]]`.  It may be able to generate code that is faster in the "likely" case at the expense of slower performance on the other branch, and that would be a win if you can tell it which of the two is in fact more likely.

Comment: GCC has `__builtin_expect` which can be used this way: `__builtin_expect(condition, true) : function1() : function2();`.

Comment: @jbk The compiler cares very much about which branch is more likely, at least for certain architectures (ie those without good branch prediction)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a different syntax to annotate ternary expressions?

No, there is no way to annotate a ternary conditional expression with the [[likely]] attribute.

> Or will I have to use an if instead?

Yes. Or alternatively, you can omit the attribute.

---

For what it's worth, it is possible using the GNU extension:

```
__builtin_expect(!!condition, 1) ? function1() : function2()
```